# Self-Identification of Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-studio

I have downloaded Ubuntu Studio both [directly](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/22.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-22.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso) and via [torrent](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/22.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-22.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent). Total Commander's compare function shows the two versions as identical and their SHA256 checksums match the one published [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/22.04.1/release/SHA256SUMS). I created a USB stick using Rufus, as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).
When I boot from the USB stick, "About this System" identifies itself as "Ubuntu Studio 22.04". The installer link on the desktop is also titled "Install Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS".  Is this normal, or did I somehow get the wrong image?

P.S. The link "[alongside the images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/22.04/release/MD256SUMS)" on the [Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS Release Notes page](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/) points to the 22.04 checksum, which is no longer available, instead of to the [22.04.1 checksum](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/22.04.1/release/SHA256SUMS). Where should I report this?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they haven't updated the link for the SHA256SUM on their website. Right now, it's showing a 404 error and no shasum is returned. I'm honestly not sure if a bug report applies to their website. However, bug reports can be [submitted here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ReportingBugs). Also, they have a [mailing list here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-studio-devel) and the #ubuntustudio-devel IRC channel on irc.libera.chat

Comment: Try the current version from 2022-08-18 19:02 (Latest images to have passed any automatic testing; try this first)  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/jammy/dvd/current/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you ask about why the description string for Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 is sometimes "Ubuntu Studio 22.04" and in another place "Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS".

As far as I understand it, the *product name* is "Ubuntu Studio 22.04". But the *minor version/point release* is 22.04.1. In addition, LTS is added to the name, to indicate *long term support*.

Which description string is used where is really up to the developers. The current point release is Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1, but the product it still Ubuntu Studio 22.04 (LTS).

The correct identification is obtained by running `lsb_release -a`. For a normal installation, this gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

As you can see, the point release and LTS status is in the "description" field, while the overall release is 22.04. This is the same for Ubuntu Studio.

Any discrepancy on the Ubuntu Studio website and/or checksums should be reported directly to the [Ubuntu Studio developers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio).

Comment: These are the answers I was looking for.  It was a challenge to implement the first part, because the Ubuntu Studio Live image simply starts with the default U.S. keyboard instead of giving you a keyboard selection menu on startup.

Comment: The second part is not so clear.  The Ubuntu Studio developers page you referenced offers many interaction possibilities, but none are identified as appropriate for reporting bugs in documentation.  I will try to report it on the Ubuntu Studio Developers' Mailing List.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine - the mailing list sounds like a good idea. 

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they haven't updated the link for the SHA256SUM on their website. Right now, it's showing a 404 error and no shasum is returned. If the SHASUM matches 22.04.1 then you have the correct image.

I'm honestly not sure if a bug report applies to their website. However, bug reports can be [submitted here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ReportingBugs).

Also, they have a [mailing list here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-studio-devel) and the #ubuntustudio-devel IRC channel on irc.libera.chat

**It looks like your best bet is probably to bring it up on the mailing list.**